# JSON not working in Indian regional setting

Tags: sharepoint-online, json, regional-settings

I have created the Sharepoint List with JSON for conditional formatting. The regional Setting for locale is "English- United States" due to which my current Date format is MM/DD/YYYY. 
[image: Regional Setting]

I have added one JSON in list which will compare input date with due date. JSON is working in current scenario.

[image: After Adding JSON]

but i when i try to change the regional setting to "English-India". Some date fields show "Invalid Date" and some are working.

[image: JSON after changing the regional Setting]

So please help me to solve this issue. and also i dont want Date and Time format in fields. We only require Date in DD/MM/YYYY format without affecting JSON function.

Comment: first thing first, For security reasons, I would suggest you to attach different screen shots which do not expose your sharepoint site and tenant.

Comment: Can you share you JSON? That way we can help you more.

Comment: {
  "$schema": "http://columnformatting.sharepointpnp.com/columnFormattingSchema.json",
  "debugMode": true,
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "[$Inspection_x0020_Call_x0020_Rais]",
  "style": {
    "background-color": {
      "operator": "?",
      "operands": [
        {
          "operator": "<=",
          "operands": [
            "[$Planned_x0020_Date_x0020__x002d_]",
            "[$Inspection_x0020_Call_x0020_Rais]"
          ]
        },
        "#E18D85",
        ""
      ]
    }
  }
}

Comment: this is JSON that i was using previously.

Comment: Any update on this.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out -> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting

```
{
   "elmType": "div",
   "txtContent": "@currentField",
   "style": {
      "color": {
         "operator": "?",
         "operands": [
            {
               "operator": "<=",
               "operands": [
                  "[$DueDate]",
                  {
                     "operator": "Date()",
                     "operands": [
                        "3/22/2017"
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            },
            "#ff0000",
            ""
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

> In your Case, it should be DD/MM/YYYY.

Thanks